# Putting data from 2 tables into a mysql view

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to merge some columns from one table into a view that contains all the data from another table. So far I have failed, here is what I have so far:

```
$create = "CREATE VIEW filter AS SELECT `".$db."`.`leads`.*, (`".$db."`.applicants.name AS lead_fname, `".$db."`.applicants.email AS lead_email, `".$db."`.applicants.appdate AS lead_added ) FROM `".$db."`.`leads`, `".$db."`.`applicants` WHERE ".$filterTerms." AND `lead_status` = '1' ORDER BY `lead_added`";
```

Any help would be appreciated

I think this is what i am trying to achieve:

View = table1 + table2

```
ID | email | name | appdate
1    data   data   data
2    data   data   data
3    data   data   data
4    data   data   data
5    data   data   data
```

Table 1

```
 ID | email | name | appdate
  1    data   data   data
  2    data   data   data
```

Table 2

```
 ID | s_email | s_name | s_appdate
 1    data      data   data
 2    data      data   data
 3    data      data   data
```

Comment: What is the error message if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated info, you want a UNION:

```
select email, name, appdate from table1
UNION
select s_email as email, s_name as name, s_appdate as appdate from table2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and apologies for the confusion, mySQL baffles me for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

You need a column in the leads table that **joins** it to the applicants table (a foreign key).
For example, if you have an application_id column in the leads table that matches the applicant_id column in the applicants table:

```
CREATE VIEW filter AS
SELECT L.*, A.name as lead_fname, A.email as lead_email, A.appdate as lead_added
FROM leads L, applications A
WHERE L.application_id=A.applicant_id;
```

You create the view in the database (using phpMyAdmin or some tool like that), not dynamically in your PHP script.

Then your PHP script can query the view as if it were a table.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM filter WHERE " . $filterTerms . "AND lead_status = '1' ORDER BY lead_added";
```

Comment: If there is no join available can I select all the data in both whilst adding the aliases for my view? All the columns are different names that's all.

Comment: You have to have a column to join the tables.  How do you know which record in the applicants table goes with the record in the leads table?

Comment: I think I'm trying to achieve something completely different. I want to add table2 to the end of my view after selecting all from table1. table 2 however has different column names from table1 and the view

Comment: Well, don't know if you can do that or why you would want to do that.  If the tables are not related to each other in any way, you can't join them.  And you can't just append two different recordsets.  You can try a UNION, but you're not going to like the results:  SELECT * FROM leads UNION SELECT * FROM applicants